# Firebase authentication: can't read data when reloading page

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Angular/Ionic app where I use Firebase/Firestore for the hosting/database. I have a login page where I authenticate using email and password first, before being able to see any data. This is working fine. However, whenever I reload/refresh the page, I get the error "ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.". However, when I navigate to a different page, the connection with Firebase seems to have been established again.

Here's part of the code for the auth.service.ts:

```
...
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
...
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {    
    // Saving user data in local storage when 
    // logged in and setting up null when logged out
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      }
    })
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  async signIn(email, password) {    
    this.afAuth.setPersistence('session').then(() => {
      return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(async res => {
          await this.setUserData(res.user);
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          });
        }).catch(err => {
          window.alert(err.message);
        })
    })
  }
...
```

For the page reload button, it's just a simple `location.reload()`.

Comment: I think your call to the db to get the user data is happening instantly which means you will get that error then by the time you navigate to a different page the authstate would have returned already and then it works. you might want to make your other db calls only after the authstate observable has returned with some answer

Comment: It's strange because I set the auth persistence to 'session', which means you don't have to re-authenticate if you just reload the page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Comment: @vdvaxel ever solve this?

Comment: any fixes for this?